# How can I rebind a pci device to a loaded linux kernel driver?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, pci

I have two video cards, both from the same manufacturer (nvidia). I'm using pci_stub to avoid binding of my secondary card to the nvidia kernel driver (in order to use it for pci-passthrough with qemu.)

I'm curious if it is possible to remove the pci_stub and rebind the secondary card to the nvidia kernel driver while the nvidia driver is **still in use**. Of course, the qemu vm is off.

I could stop X (and the vm), remove nvidia driver, remove binding, reload the nvidia driver and restart X (with whatever config). I'd like to avoid the 'stopping X' step.  In other words, I have to convince nvidia driver to recognize the second card again without unloading.

Is it possible?